# Can an HTML <form> do everything an HTML <div> can do?

Tags: forms, html

That is, can I assume all the behaviors and styles I could apply to a normal `<div>` would work the same way on a `<form>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both [block level elements](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html), so assuming that you apply a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) then, yes, they both render the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can style it exactly like any other ole block level element.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes.  They are both block-level elements.  Note that different browsers may have different preset values for their properties, such as margins.